# Hidding an element as alternative to animation

Tags: css

I have the following CSS [Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/G1Z7aH523t88umtExxtd):

```
@-webkit-keyframes ngdialog-fadeout {
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes ngdialog-fadeout {  
  0% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0; }
}

.ngdialog.ngdialog-closing .ngdialog-overlay {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: ngdialog-fadeout 0.5s;
  animation: ngdialog-fadeout 0.5s;
}

.ngdialog.ngdialog-closing .ngdialog-content {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: ngdialog-fadeout 0.5s;
  animation: ngdialog-fadeout 0.5s;
}
```

I do not want to use animation. So I tried the following:

```
.ngdialog.ngdialog-closing .ngdialog-overlay {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ngdialog.ngdialog-closing .ngdialog-content {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

I am able to hide it but after doing it every link on the page is non reactive like something is over it ...

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I tried the following:

```
.ngdialog {    
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;   
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.ngdialog-overlay {
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;  
  right: 0;
  top: 0;    
  opacity: 0.6;
  z-index: 100000;
}

.ngdialog.ngdialog-closing .ngdialog-overlay {  
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.ngdialog-content {
  background: white;
}

.ngdialog.ngdialog-closing .ngdialog-content {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

The same problem happens ...

Comment: How about setting **display: block** and **display:collapse** or **hidden**?

Comment: It does not work either ... This is really strange

Comment: This situation tbh is pretty difficult to visualise/debug. Could you possibly provide a sample?

Comment: The dialog I am using is this one: http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/ ... The CSS file is: http://likeastore.github.io/ngDialog/css/ngDialog.css

Comment: I just created an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/G1Z7aH523t88umtExxtd. Open the modal and after it close it. You will see that you will not able to open it again.And not even click on the link or the image,.

Answer (score 1):

Best way that I could find to "disable" animations from `ngDialog` is actually to speed them up so that they won't be visible anymore.

```
.ngdialog * {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.01s !important;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.01s !important;
  -o-animation-duration: 0.01s !important;
  -ms-animation-duration: 0.01s !important;
  animation-duration: 0.01s !important;
}
```